# I need help finding the equivalent resistance

Tags: basic

[image]

Hello guys , i'm new in the amazing world of electronics , and im very confused with this circuit . Im supposed to find the Req (equivalent resistance , but dont know how in this specific circuit),  plz help me out .

Comment: Redraw the circuit with the horizontal 1K resistor vertical - then it should be clearer what resistors are connected in parallel.  Then determine the equivalent of any parallell pair...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this is difficult upon initial inspection is because of the way that the circuit is drawn. First, look for common nodes, and re-draw the circuit to clearly show the parallel and series sets of resistors. This will make it much easier to simplify further:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjHd8r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I will not solve it for you, because if this is homework, that defeats the purpose.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! , it is really easy when you see it like that.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment (not enough reputation), I arrived to the same schematic that David illustrated. In addition, there is a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/391243/how-to-find-the-total-resistance-of-this-circuit/391247#391247), which I describe how to solve the circuit diagram. Redrawing helps and allows you to see clearly the elements which are parallel (share the same voltage drop across) and which are series (the elements connected in sequence).